# When is_on_floor() returns true the player can't move

Tags: godot, gdscript

This is the code, https://github.com/Gioroccovanni/SteamP2P.

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    if not is_multiplayer_authority(): return
    
    if !is_on_floor():
        velocity.y-=gravity*delta
    
    var input_dir = Input.get_vector("left", "right", "forward", "backward") #tutte le direzioni diverse da forward sono rotte :c
    var direction = (transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y))#.normalized()
    
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction.x * SPEED
        velocity.z = direction.z * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
        velocity.z = move_toward(velocity.z, 0, SPEED)
        
    print(is_on_floor())
    
    move_and_slide()
```

After trying implementing gravity (player.gd lines 27 and 28) the player falls into place(while falling it can move) but as soon as it hits the ground it can't move anymore.

Tried tuning up the speed and it doesn't affect it, when printing the velocity it actually changes with input, but doesn't seem to move the character.

Comment: Please include a [mre] directly in the question, not just a link.

Comment: Last time I asked you for a project, that was because I was thinking it was a bug in Godot, if it were then the project would also be an step in reporting the bug. However, that is not the normal procedure for StackOverflow. Here we want questions and answers that will help others who might come in the future with similar problems, and since links can rot (perhaps you want to remove that project from your github, or github changes its url scheme, or whatever) questions and answers with only a link are discouraged. Please include the relevant code snippet in the question, preferably as text.

Comment: I have added it to the question now. Edit: honestly I do not see why it would be stuck. What comes to mind is to review the ground colliders. I'll come back to try the project later.

Comment: Where is `is_on_floor` defined?  You don't check whether `velocity.y` goes negative or not.  My guess is gravity is pulling you down through the floor.

Comment: @TimRoberts [`is_on_floor`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_characterbody3d.html#class-characterbody3d-method-is-on-floor). The [`move_and_slide`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_characterbody3d.html#class-characterbody3d-method-move-and-slide) method does check for collisions. Just in case: this is not python.

Comment: @Theraot thx Theraot, I'll update the question Edit: didn't realise you already did, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have reviewed the project.

Aside from some details (notably I had to remove the `WorldEnvironment` and add a new one to have any performance), this is the big no-no: Do not use CSG with collisions inside of other physics bodies.

The player character has a CSG object inside of it that has collision enabled. This CSG object will collide with the ground, and the player will collide with it, getting stuck.

So, do not do that. Instead give the player `CollisionShape3D` children for the collisions (it already has one) and `MeshInstance3D` for the graphics.